# Use nested SELECT instead of additional joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, yii

When using a INNER JOIN in a default scope, the INNER JOIN is applied to the wrong table.
I have 4 models: `Task`, `Project`, `ProjectUser` and `User`. Their structure, relations and default scope can bee seen below.

A project is only allowed to be visible to a User, when that user is assigned to the project (through a ProjectUser link). Each project has many tasks. A task has a BELONGS_TO relation to it's parent Project. A task is only allowed to be seen by the User, if the parent Project is also visible to that User.

When I query:

```
$tasks = Task::model()->withoutChildren()->findAll();
```

it returns nothing.

My models: (heavily simplified for this post)

```
class Task extends CActiveRecord {
    /*
    Columns:
    id
    parent_task_id
    project_id
    */

    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'project' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Project', 'project_id'),
            'subTasks' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Task', 'parent_task_id', 'alias' => "Task_subTasks"),
            'parentTask' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Task', 'parent_task_id'),
        );
    }


    public function scopes() {
        $t = $this->tableAlias;
        return array(
            'withoutChildren'=>array(
                'with' => array("subTasks"),
                'select' => "COUNT(Task_subTasks.id) AS subTaskCount",
                'group' => "$t.id",
                'having' => "subTaskCount = 0",
            )
        );
    }

    public function defaultScope() {
        $t = $this->getTableAlias(false, false);
        return array(
            'with' => array(
                "project" => array(
                    'select' => false,
                    'alias' => "Task_def_". $t,
                    'joinType' => "INNER JOIN"
                )
            )
        ); 
    }
}

class Project extends CActiveRecord {
    /*
    Columns:
    id
    */

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'projectUsers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProjectUser', 'project_id'),
            'tasks' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Task', 'project_id'),
            'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'project_user(project_id, user_id)'),
        );
    }

    public function defaultScope() {
        $t = $this->getTableAlias(false, false);
        return array(
            'with' => array(
                'projectUsers' => array(
                    'joinType' => "INNER JOIN",
                    'alias' => "{$t}_pu",
                    'on' => "{$t}_pu.user_id=". User::current()->id
                )
            )
        );
    }

}

class ProjectUser extends CActiveRecord {
    /*
    Columns:
    id
    project_id
    user_id
    */

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'project' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Project', 'project_id'),
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }
}

class User extends CActiveRecord {

}
```

I do understand why it doesn't work. The query yii generates, is: (again, heavily simplified)

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Task_subTasks.id) AS subTaskCount, (all the other field...) FROM `task` `t`  

INNER JOIN `project` `Task_def_t` ON (`t`.`project_id`=`Task_def_t`.`id`) AND 

INNER JOIN `project_user` `Task_def_t_pu`
ON (`Task_def_t_pu`.`project_id`=`Task_def_t`.`id`) AND
(Task_def_t_pu.user_id=6)  

LEFT OUTER JOIN
`task` `Task_subTasks` ON (`Task_subTasks`.`parent_task_id`=`t`.`id`) AND

INNER JOIN `project`
`Task_def_Task_subTasks` ON
(`Task_subTasks`.`project_id`=`Task_def_Task_subTasks`.`id`) AND

INNER JOIN `project_user`
`Task_def_Task_subTasks_pu` ON
(`Task_def_Task_subTasks_pu`.`project_id`=`Task_def_Task_subTasks`.`id`)
AND (Task_def_Task_subTasks_pu.user_id=6)  

GROUP BY t.id 

HAVING (subTaskCount = 0)
```

In this case the 4th and 5th JOINs apply to the `'task' 't'` table. Which shouldn't happen. Now they limit the original query even more, which results in the query returning 0 rows.

However the 4th and 5th JOINs should be applied to `LEFT OUTER JOIN 'task' 'Task_subTasks'` (I'm not sure 'applied' is the correct term here). Anyway, this is what I expect Yii to generate:

```sql
SELECT (all the other field...) FROM `task` `t`  

INNER JOIN `project` `Task_def_t` ON (`t`.`project_id`=`Task_def_t`.`id`) AND 

INNER JOIN `project_user` `Task_def_t_pu`
ON (`Task_def_t_pu`.`project_id`=`Task_def_t`.`id`) AND
(Task_def_t_pu.user_id=6)  

WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(Task_subTasks.id) FROM `task` `Task_subTasks`

    INNER JOIN `project`
    `Task_def_Task_subTasks` ON
    (`Task_subTasks`.`project_id`=`Task_def_Task_subTasks`.`id`) AND

    INNER JOIN `project_user`
    `Task_def_Task_subTasks_pu` ON
    (`Task_def_Task_subTasks_pu`.`project_id`=`Task_def_Task_subTasks`.`id`)
    AND (Task_def_Task_subTasks_pu.user_id=6)  

    WHERE (`Task_subTasks`.`parent_task_id`=`t`.`id`)

) = 0

GROUP BY t.id
```

I edited this simple query without testing. However, I transformed the original (massive) query the same way, and now it works!

My question: how do I instruct Yii to query it using a nested SELECT instead of appending all the joins to the same table?

Comment: When you have something along the lines of `WHERE (SELECT <aggregate>) = 0`, you really have a `WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` condition, which the optimizer _may_ optimize better.  Sorry, I can't help you with yii though.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations I will simply do:

`$tasks = Task::model()->findBySql('your_sql_here');`

and will enjoy the correct answers. However you will have to write the SQL itself, but this will give you a lot of opportunity to optimize it and even to add extra elements to it.

For example you can return everything from the task table and also the project name with something like: `select Task.*, Project.name as project_name`

Then you will have access to extra property `$tasks[0]->project_name` In some situations this can be very handy.

Yii is really flexible. :)